# Reducing std::bind template code bloat?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, bind, stdbind

I've written an object that stores a `std::function<void(void*)>`, which is passed in as an argument to the constructor.  The object will later call back this std::function at some point in the future.  This is implemented and working great.

In each class which uses this object, they call the constructor in the initialization list like so:

```
mCallbackObj(std::bind(&MyClass::MyFunc, this, _1))
```

However, I've found that every class which contains this object as a member is increasing my codespace by ~2K.  With potentially hundreds of places where this object will be used, and limited codespace options (this is an embedded product), a 2k hit per use isn't acceptable.

One interesting observation is that if a class has a second object:

```
mCallbackObj2(std::bind(&MyClass::MyOtherFunc, this, _1))
```

this only increases codespace by some ~150 bytes - very acceptable!  It is only when the object is used in different classes that I see the 2K hit.  Putting the classes all in one .cpp file doesn't help - still a 2k hit per class that contains this object.

I've played around with using `extern template class std::function<void(void*)>;`, but this had no impact on ROM size.

I am using gcc 4.8.  I'd love to use `std::function` and `std::bind`, but am about to give up and switch to class method pointers.  They wouldn't be nearly as clean, but hopefully more ROM efficient.

Before I give up on this, are there any other options to help reduce my template codespace bloat?

Comment: I wonder whether the situation changes if you use `[this](void* p){ return this->MyFunc(p); }` in place of `bind`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Might be slightly better, but `std::function` still generates plenty of boilerplate by itself.

Comment: std::function is probably the cause of the bloat.  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zt7ThwVfap0)  You could try replacing the bind with a lambda, but that won't likely reduce binary size.

Comment: You could try a lightweight alternative like this [fast delegate](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14730/impossibly-fast-delegate-in-c11), using the member function pointer template variant: `delegate<void(void*)>::from<Foo, &Foo::bar>(&foo);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dug into this a bit more and watched [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1735922/john)'s video on `std::function`.  In the [video](https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?t=1975), STL recommends using lambdas over `std::bind` for a few reasons.

I tried converting the code to use a Lambda, which is exactly what [@Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) recommended above.  It is significantly better.

```
mCallbackObj(std::bind(&MyClass::MyFunc, this, _1))
```

Takes an additional 2,888 bytes of codespace.  Instead using

```
mCallbackObj([this](void *info){MyFunc(info);})
```

Only takes an additional 812 bytes!  This is significantly better, and good enough for my use-case.  For C++ programmers unfamiliar with the syntax of std::bind, the lambda solution is also easier to read.

---

**Update -**

After bumping to GCC 6.0 and tweaking our compiler flags (we weren't always passing in -O2 previously), I've retested this.

```
Lambda:            216 bytes
std::bind:         221 bytes
function pointer:  228 bytes
```

All 3 are now much more reasonable.  We are mostly using lambdas, as they are the easiest to read once developers are familiar with the syntax.